# cakephp saveAssociated and validation foreign_key fails

Tags: validation, cakephp, cakephp-2.6

I have two models that we're going to name Model and RelatedModel. Model has many RelatedModel. So if I add foreign key validation on validation array like:

```
public $validate = array(
'foreignKey' => array(
            'rule' => 'numeric',
            'required' => true,
            'message' => 'The id of relatedmodel should be a number'
        )
)
```

After I create a add() function to save new registers and in this function I use saveAssociated with validation true, this one fails throwing an error 'The id of relatedmodel should be a number'.

I'm debugging the code and saveAssociated checks validation of both models at the same time and before save Model.

Is this an issue?

I think what this function should do is to validate Model, save it, add foreignKey of RelatedModel and then validate it before save.

Answer (score 1):

I came into this issue only recently. It's not an issue, `saveAssociated()` is designed to work this way unfortunately.

What you can do is alter the `required => true` on the fly using the model validator. Check out the book for more information.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#dynamically-change-validation-rules

Comment: tha's a good point, I think it's the best solucion. Anything I keep thinking that's an issue of saveAssociated validation.

Answer (score 0):

This is working as would be expected with your given rule. `required` in Cake means it expects the value of `foreignKey` to be set in the save data prior to saving. All the validation will happen before Cake saves the data (and therefore before `foreignKey` is generated).

You shouldn't need to validate that it is numeric if you are allowing Cake to generate this for you behind the scenes. If you want to check that it is being passed in the data for an `UPDATE` you could modify the [`required`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#required) to be only for an `update` like this:-

```
public $validate = array(
    'foreignKey' => array(
        'rule' => 'numeric',
        'required' => 'update',
        'message' => 'The id of relatedmodel should be a number'
    )
)
```

Personally I wouldn't bother validating foreign keys unless a user is setting them rather than Cake.

**Update:**

To validate the `foreignKey` if it exists in a form submission you can drop the `required` option from the validation rule:-

```
public $validate = array(
    'foreignKey' => array(
        'rule' => 'numeric',
        'message' => 'The id of relatedmodel should be a number'
    )
);
```

This will allow you to pass data where the `foreignKey` is not present without throwing a validation error whilst validating it if it is.

Comment: I need to check because sometimes I have select forms to select an id, if I don't check whether the foreign_key is numeric or notEmpty, I'm not able to show an error message if select is empty.

Comment: I've updated my answer accordingly then. Basically drop the `required` option as it isn't what you want.

Comment: I think this is a workaround, but key should be validated in my previous case. If you use save with Model, set key to RelatedModel and then save again. Everything works.

Comment: I suspect you're misunderstanding what `required` means in Cake. It is not the same as `notEmpty`. It means that it must exist in the submitted data which in your case it is not so your validation rule is incorrect. My updated answer shows a validation rule that will be checked whenever the data is being set manually (*i.e.* via the user) rather than by Cake. If Cake is setting it then there is no need to validate it. If Cake is failing to create the foreign key then it is because you have a bug in your code rather than a validation issue.

Comment: But I have another controllers with save(). I underestand perfectly required, and the foreignKey should be required when you use save() with a select element in views.